# Tags supported by Android HCE

Tags: android, nfc, host, emulation, hce

I am trying to emulate Android NFC using my Nexus 4 device as part of a Host Card Emulation demo. I want to know if all of the NFC Tags are supported by HCE or just specific tags?

Is ISO-DEP just an example, or is it the only one that works?

Answer (score 3):

Reading [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#SupportedProtocols) usually helps:

> Specifically, Android 4.4 supports emulating cards that are based on the NFC-Forum 
>   ISO-DEP specification (based on ISO/IEC 14443-4) and process Application Protocol Data Units 
>   (APDUs) as defined in the ISO/IEC 7816-4 specification. Android mandates emulating ISO-DEP 
>   only on top of the Nfc-A (ISO/IEC 14443-3 Type A) technology. Support for Nfc-B (ISO/IEC 
>   14443-4 Type B) technology is optional. The layering of all these specifications is shown
>   in the [figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDbIf.png).

Comment: Specifically, what I am trying to do is demonstrate HCE. I have service which extends HostApduService. I have a NfcTag card which returns NfcA as Tag. The overridden method processCommandApdu method in the Service never gets called. I am using Payment as category in xml.

Comment: Check your `<host-apdu-service>` definition and make sure you are sending the proper SELECT command. The services is only called after SELECT succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

If a tag supports ISO-DEP/7816-4, then you can use HCE. 
If a tag supports NfcA or NfcB only, it won't work. Check the TagTechnology support list.

1. Contactless credit card uses ISO-DEP/7816-4.
2. NFC Type 4 Mifare DesFire also uses ISO-DEP/7816-4. 
   You can use HCE to talk to it.
   However, using NDEF is much more practical. ISO-DEP simply wraps low level Mifare command; much more harder to use.